# I can't figure out the django qeryset for retriving a value from a field by a condition

Tags: python, django, django-models

My model like this

```
mobile_name = models.CharField("Mobile Name", max_length=50)
opinion = models.CharField('Comments', max_length=2000)
total_mark = models.FloatField('Total Mark')
```

the sql query should like this `"SELECT total_mark FROM tablexyz WHERE mobile_name=xyz"`

I found this

```
MyModel.objects.filter(mobile_name='xyz')
```

but I think it will fetch the all the field values. I just want the total_mark nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) to fetch only certain values (example from the docs):

```
>>> Blog.objects.values('id', 'name')
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Beatles Blog'}]
```

In your case:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(mobile_name='xyz').values('total_mark')
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. sk1p. I was looking for something like this.